# Run cronjob in Ubuntu 14.04 Server

Tags: server, cron

How can I run crontab in Ubuntu 14.04 server?

I am using CodeIgniter PHP framework.

I get some code from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430509/cannot-run-cron-job-for-a-php-script) and tried this:

```
*/5 * * * * wget -q http://IPADDRESS/ws/cronjob/index
```

But this is not working. Can anyone look into this?

Comment: Do report on suggested solutions' results: Did it work, did it not work and why. Notify your helper with "@name", as in my case: @Cbhihe.

Comment: Please clarify what you are doing. Why are you mentioning a PHP framework? Are you trying to run this from PHP? Where exactly did you add the `*/5 * ...` line you show?

Comment: Have a look at a similar post http://askubuntu.com/questions/143682/cron-job-fails-for-any-time-other-than-default. It will give you a few good leads to start troubleshooting your issue...

Comment: @terdon i told that i am using `Codeigniter` - PHP framework and `cronjob` is my controller and `index` is function. i am using `Amazon EC2`

Answer (score 2):

Try  `/usr/bin/wget` instead of `wget`.

It is because cron does not import your environment and in particular does not know about $PATH.

Comment: True, but `/usr/bin` is in cron's default path, this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @terdon: ok, my bad.

Comment: my code is working but in that i have push notification code also. that is not working.